# MySQL query working in PHPMyAdmin but not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have written a MySQL query:

```
$feedItem->tags =

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * 
    FROM qzxh_k2_tags, qzxh_k2_tags_xref
    WHERE qzxh_k2_tags.id = qzxh_k2_tags_xref.tagID
    AND qzxh_k2_tags.id = '406'
    AND qzxh_k2_tags_xref.itemID = '".$item->id"'");

while($tag = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
echo $tag;
```

The query itself shows the results I need in PHPMyAdmin, but for some reason this isn't showing anything when used in PHP. Any ideas where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: if those id are number you do not need ' around them

Comment: what is `$feedItem->tags =`?

Comment: Where is your connection object? And you are missing the Concatination operator(.) after $item->id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing concatenation operator (dot)

Change

```
"SELECT * 
    FROM qzxh_k2_tags, qzxh_k2_tags_xref
    WHERE qzxh_k2_tags.id = qzxh_k2_tags_xref.tagID
    AND qzxh_k2_tags.id = '406'
    AND qzxh_k2_tags_xref.itemID = '".$item->id"'"
// You are missing dot . here                  ^
```

To

```
"SELECT * 
FROM qzxh_k2_tags, qzxh_k2_tags_xref
WHERE qzxh_k2_tags.id = qzxh_k2_tags_xref.tagID
AND qzxh_k2_tags.id = '406'
AND qzxh_k2_tags_xref.itemID = '".$item->id."'"
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Use proper string concatenation in your sql query. Find below corrected query.

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * 
    FROM qzxh_k2_tags, qzxh_k2_tags_xref
    WHERE qzxh_k2_tags.id = qzxh_k2_tags_xref.tagID
    AND qzxh_k2_tags.id = '406'
    AND qzxh_k2_tags_xref.itemID = '".$item->id."'");
```